# Unnest fitted glm models

Tags: r, nested, models

I have a tibble with nested glm models. I nest over a variable (`region`) and run a function  `region_model` that fits the model.

```
# toy data
test_data = data.frame(region = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE),
              x = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                                   y = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                                   z = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>% arrange(region)

# nest
by_region = test_data %>%
              group_by(region) %>%
              nest()


# glm function 
region_model  <- function(df) {
 glm(x ~ y + z, data = df, family = "binomial")
}              

# run the model  
    by_region = by_region %>% mutate(mod_rat = data %>% map(region_model))
```

The resulting tibble looks like this:

```
> by_region
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  region               data   mod_rat
  <fctr>             <list>    <list>
1      a <tibble [352 x 3]> <S3: glm>
2      b <tibble [329 x 3]> <S3: glm>
3      c <tibble [319 x 3]> <S3: glm>
```

My purpose is to unnest the models to calculate marginal effects. I have tried it and I have got this error:

```
> unnest(by_region, mod_rat)
Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [mod_rat]
```

I wonder whether it possible to use `unnest` on this type of objects  (`<S3: glm>`) and in case not, whether there is an alternative to get these estimates.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: You can't nest models like that.  What part of the models do you need for your calculations?  If it's a single statistic, you could always extract that and then unnest.  Or you can perform calculations using your nested original data and models like this:   `by_region %>% mutate(results = map2(data, mod_rat, foo))`

Comment: The idea of the `broom` package and `nest`ing is that model results should be converted into tidy table like format using functions like `augment`, `glance`etc. This tabular results can then be `unnest`-ed. Your model are still in their original untidy format and `unnest` cannot just magic them into a tabular output. Have a look here for examples:http://omaymas.github.io/Climate_Change_ExpAnalysis/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I have done the latter actually. My initial point was to use the model (gsm object) to compute the marginal effects with `margins()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, the `margins` package has had some recent updates which will help you do this in a tidy fashion. In particular a `margins_summary()` function has been added that can be mapped onto nested model objects.

[This issue](https://github.com/leeper/margins/issues/94) on GitHub has the details.

Here is some code that works with your example

Using data from above

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(margins)

# toy data
test_data <- data.frame(region = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE),
                             x = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                             y = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                             z = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
arrange(region)

# nest
by_region <- 
    test_data %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    nest()

# glm function 
region_model  <- function(df) {
   glm(x ~ y + z, data = df, family = "binomial")
}              

# run the model  
by_region %<>% 
  mutate(mod_rat = map(data, region_model))
```

Using the `margins_summary()` function via `purrr:map2()` to compute marginal effects (I have included both methods for calculating the marginal effects with logistic regression as described in the package vignette)

```
by_region %<>% 
    mutate(marginals      = map2(mod_rat, data, ~margins_summary(.x, data = .y)),
           marginals_link = map2(mod_rat, data, ~margins_summary(.x, data = .y, type = "link")))
```

We can now unnest either of the created list columns with the marginal effect data

```
by_region %>% 
   unnest(marginals) -> region_marginals
   region_marginals
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  region factor      AME      SE      z     p
    <fct>  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
  1 a      y      -9.38e-4 9.71e-4 -0.966 0.334
  2 a      z       3.59e-2 5.55e-2  0.647 0.517
  3 b      y       1.14e-3 9.19e-4  1.24  0.215
  4 b      z      -2.93e-2 5.38e-2 -0.545 0.586 
  5 c      y       4.67e-4 9.77e-4  0.478 0.633
  6 c      z      -3.32e-2 5.49e-2 -0.604 0.546
# ... with 2 more variables: lower <dbl>,
#   upper <dbl>
```

And plot nicely

```
region_marginals %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(factor, AME), AME, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "#AAAAAA") +
  geom_pointrange() +
  facet_wrap(~region) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]